# How to raise an event when Enter is pressed into an InputText in PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, tkinter, pysimplegui

I'm new with Python & PySimpleGUI and I don't know how to force my application to handle the event `<Enter>` key; this is my code:

```
    # Text field
    sg.InputText(
        key=key,
        default_text='',
        enable_events=True,
    ),


    ...


    window = self.graphic_interface.window

    while self.is_running:
        self.event, self.values = window.read(timeout=0)

    ...


    if event in INSERT_SN_KEYS:
        key = event

        if values[key]is not None:
            # Accept only numbers
            if values[key][-1] not in '0123456789':
                window[key].update(values[key][:-1])
```

My code can handle any key pressed by user except `<Enter>`; I haven't found any argument for InputText similar to "bind_return_key=True" used into Button class.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using method `bind("<Return>", key_modifier)` of `sg.Input` after window finalized, it will generate an event `sg.Input().Key + key_modifier` when this element focused and Enter key pressed.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme("DarkBlue3")
sg.set_options(font=("Courier New", 16))

layout = [
    [sg.Input("Enter to generate an event",     key='Input1')],
    [sg.Input("Enter not to generate an event", key='Input2')],
]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True)
window['Input1'].bind("<Return>", "_Enter")

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == "Input1" + "_Enter":
        print(event)

window.close()
```

Comment: Perfect, is exactly what i need. Thank you

Comment: How do you know to use `<Return>`?  What if I want to bind my keypad's "Enter" key, which doesn't seem to register as either `<Return>` or `<Enter>`?

Comment: @DarienMarks the keypad's "Enter" is registered as `<KP_Enter>`, so you can add another binding with that one.